# Fast operations on IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone project that requires searching through a database of around 70,000 XML entries, selecting those items that match a query, and returning those items to be displayed in a listBox.

Using LINQ, I can get the actual search to occur in a reasonable amount of time (< 2 seconds). However, it appears that loading up a listBox with a large amount of entries takes a rather unreasonable amount of time. Because of that, I'd like to display 10 items, and then allow the user to press Next, if they want to see more.

The problem I'm having is that performing any sort of operation on an object of type IEnumerable takes a completely unreasonable amount of time. This includes Count, .Take(10), and .ToList(); Each one of those operations takes approximately a minute to run, which is completely unreasonable for the software I'm writing.

Ultimately, I don't care what format the data is in, as long as I can easily access entries by position. I'm just looking for a solution that would allow me to easily output this data.

Comment: Is an embedded database an option? Also, what about if it is initially a List (IEnumerable used later or not) object? The IEnumerable operations are somewhat smart about the underlying type..

Comment: Are you sure the LINQ query is actually executing and taking 2 seconds?  Could be you're seeing deferred execution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx

Comment: @pst : An embedded database is ideally not an option. My program uses government data, which is served out as XML. I would rather not maintain a second copy of the data in a better format, and I would rather not have the program spend the first few minutes of booting to pull the latest data and convert it to SQLite or another format.

Comment: how often does the xml data change?

Comment: Approximately every two weeks or so. Small changes are made to the database, though I don't know if the changes are appended, or the entire file is remade.

Comment: Can you show some of your code? As some people have said, it's likely deferred execution. Your best bet is to `ToList()` the data (or something similar, as appropriate) then work with the in-memory representation which should be extremely fast.

Comment: To add to @yamen comments, I'd also recommend ToList(), but a sample of your code will help. Also, you can serialise the data to IsolatedStorage, no need for conversion to SQLite.  Just cache it for the duration of the App or forever, until signalled that the prime source has changed (as you say above every 2 weeks) - this means fast loading for 1 week and 4 days :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explicitly state this, but I assume you are operating on XElement or XmlElement. You should first deserialize the XML to Objects. (There are tool which can generate an XSD from a given XML and then you can get the classes from the XSD).

After that your LINQ should be much faster and the data should need less RAM also.

If that wasn't right please update your question with more details.